# How to configure Rate Limiting on Kafka Topic while publishing message?

Tags: apache-kafka, micronaut, micronaut-kafka

We are using Kafka to process events. We have 2 use cases which resulting more events.

1. Sometimes we are getting lot of bot traffic.
2. Some of our customers are generating more traffic frequently.

This is causing delay in processing other customers events.

So I want to add some rate limiting based on the customer. As per my research there is no way to add rate limiting while publishing message to Topic.

Our application is developed on Micronaut framework.

Is there a way to add limits at consumer level?

Is there any java related frameworks on top of Kafka to implement rate limiting ?

Answer (score 1):

Per-customer limits would be challenging to implement with kafka quotas. Instead, you might want to check out [resilience4j-micronaut](https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/getting-started-7) and do this limiting on the producer side.

You can use a RateLimiterRegistry to create and retrieve RateLimiter instances:

```
RateLimiterConfig config = RateLimiterConfig.custom()
  .limitRefreshPeriod(Duration.ofMillis(1))
  .limitForPeriod(10)
  .timeoutDuration(Duration.ofMillis(25))
  .build();

// Create registry
RateLimiterRegistry rateLimiterRegistry = RateLimiterRegistry.of(config);

// Use registry
RateLimiter rateLimiterWithDefaultConfig = rateLimiterRegistry
  .rateLimiter("name1");

RateLimiter rateLimiterWithCustomConfig = rateLimiterRegistry
  .rateLimiter("name2", config);
```

You can decorate any `Callable`, `Supplier`, `Runnable`, `Consumer`, `CheckedRunnable`, `CheckedSupplier`, `CheckedConsumer` or `CompletionStage` with a RateLimiter:

```
// Decorate your call to BackendService.doSomething()
CheckedRunnable restrictedCall = RateLimiter
    .decorateCheckedRunnable(rateLimiter, backendService::doSomething);

Try.run(restrictedCall)
    .andThenTry(restrictedCall)
    .onFailure((RequestNotPermitted throwable) -> LOG.info("Wait before call it again :)"));
```

For per-customer or per-user throttling, you would need an instance of RateLimiter per entity to be limited:

```
LimiterManager limiterManager = new LimiterManager();

String customerNameUnique = "Acme123"; // // Get from current client request
final RateLimiter rateLimiter = limiterManager.getLimiter(customerNameUnique);

Runnable runnable = RateLimiter.decorateRunnable(rateLimiter, new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO: Your code here, publishing events to kafka topic
    }
});

Try.runRunnable(runnable).onFailure(
        error -> System.out.print(error)
);

// Use a LimiterManager utility class to create / retrieve per-customer instances of RateLimiter
public static class LimiterManager {
    
    final ConcurrentMap<String, RateLimiter> keyRateLimiters = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, RateLimiter>();

    final RateLimiterConfig rateLimiterConfig = RateLimiterConfig.custom().timeoutDuration(Duration.ofMillis(100))
            .limitRefreshPeriod(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
            .limitForPeriod(25) // Max 25 accesses per 1 second
            .build();

    public RateLimiter getLimiter(String entity) {
        return keyRateLimiters.compute(entity, (key, limiter) -> {
                return (limiter == null) ? RateLimiter.of(entity, rateLimiterConfig) : limiter;
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Request throttling can be controlled with [quotas on the broker](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#design_quotas), which the clients then internally understand without changing code (other than adding authentication to specify client groups).

Answer (score 0):

You are asking about rate limiting, but what you are trying to achieve is prioritizing processing of data, don't you? This is not an easy thing, because it really depends on your flow, but I'd suggest to consider couple things:

1. What is the bottleneck? Is it a consumer? Where is the back pressure coming from?
2. Do you produce to the same topic? Maybe you want to split traffic to multiple topics?
3. I've worked on a bit similar product and used Flink, that provides ability to configure `parallelism` per source (or route), which provides QoS for main data flow and in case that lower priority has spikes in incoming data it would cause back pressure for its processing, but without affect on higher priority flow.

Comment: Events are produced to same topic, but routed to multiple partitions.

Comment: Bottleneck is at a consumer level to process events, because some customers are producing lot of events. So that other customers events are waiting until completion of piled events.

Comment: Have the same pain. Consumer service has 3 logical steps - consume, process and output. While consume is fastest and process is the slowest of them (about 70% of overall e2e time). What Flink allows us is to provide different parallelism for each step. So messages from a single thread of consume are routed to 8 threads of processing.
[See the screenshot link of an example service](https://imgur.com/a/dN1ruRp)

Comment: @Awesome I've skimmed over the documentation of the framework and I think you can apply same approach within it. You can use ThreadPool or whatever is more comfortable to you. Use main service only for pulling records and your ThreadPool to process it. 
The hardest part - you will need to handle back pressure in some way to control consuming of the records (that's why Akka-based frameworks are so popular in Kafka ecosystem)